# Random positioning and movement of a rabbit on a table

Tags: python, object-oriented, python-2.x, random, simulation

I was inspired by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1666792/what-is-the-chance-that-a-rabbit-wont-fall-of-a-table-if-you-put-it-somewhere-a):

> If you would put a rabbit randomly on a circular table with radius r=
>   1 meter and it moves 1 meter in a random direction, what is the
>   chance it won't fall off?

I decided to develop a program to manually test this scenario. My code will run as many tests as you want with (hopefully) more tests resulting in a correct answer. I know a bit of C++, but have decided to learn Python recently.

My code does the following:

- Initialises a random starting within a circle with radius 1
- Moves 1 unit in a random direction
- Updates the pass/fail rate depending on if the movement resulted in a position within the original circle

```
import math
import random

class RandPoint:
    x = 0
    y = 0

    def __init__(self):
        self.x = random.uniform(-1,1)
        self.y = random.uniform(-1,1)

    def move(self):
        angle = random.uniform(0, 2 * math.pi)
        self.x+=math.cos(angle)
        self.y+=math.sin(angle)

    def check(self):
        return math.sqrt(math.pow(self.x,2)+math.pow(self.y,2)) < 1


passed = 0.0
num = int(raw_input("How many trials would you like? \n"))

for value in range (1,num):
    startingpoint = RandPoint()

    while not(startingpoint.check()):
        startingpoint = RandPoint()

    startingpoint.move()
    passed += int(startingpoint.check())

print (str(num) + " trys, " + str(passed) + " passes, " +      str((passed/num)*100) + "%")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Sampling

This is your approach to placing the rabbit randomly on a circular table:

> ```
> startingpoint = RandPoint()
>
> while not(startingpoint.check()):
>     startingpoint = RandPoint()
> ```

How many tries does it take to place a rabbit?  Each attempt succeeds with a probability \$p = \dfrac{\pi}{4}\$, so the expected number of tries is

$$\frac{\pi}{4}\left(1 + 2\left(1 - \frac{\pi}{4}\right) + 3\left(1 - \frac{\pi}{4}\right)^2 + 4\left(1 - \frac{\pi}{4}\right)^3 + \ldots\right) \approx 1.273$$

Can it be done without retrying?  [Yes.](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiskPointPicking.html)  You can use

$$\begin{array}{rl}
x =& \sqrt{r}\ \cos \theta \\
y =& \sqrt{r}\ \sin \theta
\end{array}$$

… where \$r\$ is sampled uniformly from the interval [0, 1] and \$\theta\$ is sampled uniformly on [0, 2π].

Which is better for performance: taking a chance with looping (and consuming 27% more random numbers), or performing a square root and trigonometric calculations?  It's hard to say in advance, but it turns out that the performance of my solution below is about the same.  I think that the \$\langle \sqrt{r}\ \cos \theta, \sqrt{r}\ \sin \theta\rangle\$ method is more elegant.

### Critique

In Python 2, classes should explicitly derive from `object`.

In `RandPoint`, `x = 0` and `y = 0` are unnecessary, and in fact misleading.  Those variables are not the same as `self.x` and `self.y`.

In this case, `math.pow()` should be written more succinctly using the exponentiation operator, since you [don't need the validation that `math.pow()` performs](//stackoverflow.com/q/10282674/1157100).  You also don't need `math.sqrt()` in `check()`.

`move()` and `check()` are specific to the exercise at hand and feel out of place in a `RandPoint` class.  Furthermore, based on just the method name, it's not obvious what `check()` would check.  Perhaps `is_in_unit_disc()` would be clearer, but I would choose to reorganize that code altogether.

`passed` is a count, so it should be an `int` rather than a `float`.  A better way to count a bunch of boolean values is to use the built-in `sum()` function with a generator expression.

The idiom to repeat something `num` times is `for _ in xrange(num): …`.  By starting a 1, you skipped one iteration.

To print the result, don't do so many string concatenations.  You can use `str.format()` instead.

### Suggested solution

```
import math
import random

class Point(object):
    @staticmethod
    def random_polar(r=None):
        """Pick a point in a random direction with some magnitude.
           If r=1, this samples a unit circle uniformly.
           If r=None, this samples a unit disc uniformly."""
        if r is None:
            r = random.uniform(0, 1)**0.5
        theta = random.uniform(0, 2 * math.pi)
        return Point(r * math.cos(theta), r * math.sin(theta))

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def add(self, other):
        self.x += other.x
        self.y += other.y
        return self

def rabbit_trial():
    """Rabbit at a random point in the unit disc moves one unit in
       a random direction.  Return True if the rabbit is still in
       the unit disc, or False if the rabbit is outside the disc."""
    p = Point.random_polar().add(Point.random_polar(r=1))
    return p.x**2 + p.y**2 < 1**2

trials = int(raw_input("How many trials would you like? "))
inside = sum(rabbit_trial() for _ in xrange(trials))
print '{} tries, {} passes, {}%'.format(trials, inside, 100.0 * inside / trials)
```

Comment: Is it recommended to rename the adding method to `__add__`, so that `Point.random_polar().add(Point.random_polar(r=1))` becomes `Point.random_polar() + Point.random_polar(r=1)` ? 
Othe suggestion: add a `center_square_distance` @property to the `Point` class

Comment: @oliverpool I did have similar thoughts. Changing `.add()` to `.__add__()` would be cleaner, but in that case I would change `Point` to be an immutable subclass of `namedtuple`; that adds about 30% to the execution time. I did consider adding a `.magnitude` property (but that would reintroduce the square root), and I considered `.square_of_magnitude` to be too unconventional for my taste.

Answer (score 0):

**Style**

Python has a style guide called [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). I highly recommend reading it and applying it *when relevant*.

Among the details that could be improved in your code :

- whitespace : there should be no space before `(` (when calling function) ; there should be a single space after `,` (when calling a function with multiple arguments) and around operators (like `+=`).
- useless parenthesis

**Bug**

I've found a bug in your code : the number of elements in `range(1, num)` is not `num`, it is `num-1`. If you want `n` elements, you should use `range(0, num)` which can be more concisely written `range(num)`.

**Tiny improvements**

In your `RandPoint` class, you do not need to have `x` and `y`. It is not needed and will only bring confusion.

You do not need to convert the return for `check` in `int`. Boolean are integers with value 0 and 1 so everything will work just fine.

`passed` doesn't need to be a float number, you could give it `0` as an initial value (and not `0.0`). I guess you did this only to be able to perform a floatint point division. The best way to do so is to use `from __future__ import division` because this is the default behavior for divisions in Python 3. This brings me to the fact that if you have no good reason to use Python 2 (dependencies on libraries using Python 2 only), you should try to use Python 3 to take the good habits.

You have different methods to format strings which are all better than string concatenation. You'll find [a lot of documentation](https://pyformat.info/) about this.

The plural for "try" is "tries", not "trys".

At this stage, the code looks like:

from **future** import division
import math
import random

class RandPoint:
    def **init**(self):
        self.x = random.uniform(-1, 1)
        self.y = random.uniform(-1, 1)

```
def move(self):
    angle = random.uniform(0, 2 * math.pi)
    self.x += math.cos(angle)
    self.y += math.sin(angle)

def check(self):
    return math.sqrt(math.pow(self.x, 2) + math.pow(self.y, 2)) < 1


passed = 0
num = 10000  # int(raw_input("How many trials would you like? \n"))

for value in range(num):
    startingpoint = RandPoint()

    while not startingpoint.check():
        startingpoint = RandPoint()

    startingpoint.move()
    passed += startingpoint.check()

print "%d tries, %d passes, %f%%" % (num, passed, 100 * passed / num)
```

**Code organisation**

Your class works may be improved.

*To be added later*.